# IntelliJ and Google Web Toolkit

Tags: java, gwt, intellij-idea

I'm currently looking at Google Web Toolkit and wish to give it a run about, however I use IntelliJ.
According to IntelliJ's website, IntelliJ has built in native support for GWT, however, I don't seem to be able to setup it as the website outlines... I'm wondering if it's due to the fact I'm using community edition, or if I'm just not seeing the full picture.

Could somebody point me in the direction of any tutorials related to setting up GWT with IntelliJ so that I can get underway creating an app with it?

Answer (score 1):

Do you have IntelliJ Community Edition?

There is no GWT support in the Community Edition.

But you still can use it, check this [tips](http://java.dzone.com/tips/gwt-development-intellij-idea).

Otherwise: `Create a new project > Java > Google web toolkit`.

If you dont see it there:

Open the Project Structure dialog (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>).

---

Go to Facets, and select GWT.
In the Defaults tab, specify the path to the GWT installation folder. 
Click OK.

This is a nice [example](http://kiahu.com/tutorial/working-with-gwt-maven-and-intellij-idea/) of Maven with GWT.

Comment: That will be why, I am using CE. There's no mention of no GWT support on the website in CE! Thank you for your link, I'll set it up with that, thank you.

Comment: This is actually mentioned in http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/ (select "community edition" and see how GWT is grayed out, or head to the [editions comparison page](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/editions_comparison_matrix.html))